# multicast in private network

Tags: networking, multicast

I'am confused about multicast in a private subnet.

Currently I have the following situation:

```
subnet 10.0.0.0/24
NAT router 10.0.0.1 (ubuntu)
pc1 10.0.0.2
pc2 10.0.0.3
```

`pc1` and `pc2` using the multicast address `228.0.0.4`.
Does this mean its only for this network?
Are the `pc` still "protected" by the NAT?

Answer (score 0):

you are using global multicast range (internet wide ) of address.So 228.0.0.4 may not be only for this network.
  Multicast and NAT are not interrelated.

Comment: what you mean with "may not be only for this network"? I dont own 228.0.0.4 but it is working (in private subnet). I want to understand why its working.

Comment: If i send a UDP package to all members of 228.0.0.4. Does the router route it to the public internet?